# ループによって表示させているリストの表示行数を、プルダウンで選択できるようにしたい

Tags: javascript, php

こんにちは。お世話になります。よろしくお願いいたします。

**やりたいこと**
Javascript/Jquery/PHPのどれかを使って以下リンク先のようなことができるようにしたいです。

[JavaScriptを使用してテーブルの表示行数を3行、5行、10行とユーザーが自由に切り替えられるようにする方法](https://incloop.com/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4/)

色々調べたのですが、見合った情報が見つけられませんでしたので、こちらで質問させていただいた次第です。

**以下、コードを記載します。**

```
//プルダウン設置
<div>　　
        <span>Show :</span>  
        <select id="list-num" onchange="change_table()">
            <option value="30" selected>30</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
</div>
    
//データ取り込み＆配列の作成    
    <?php
    define('API_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('API_USER', 'root');
    define('API_PASSWORD', '');
    define('API_NAME', 'parties');
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(API_HOST, API_USER, API_PASSWORD, API_NAME) or die('Error connecting to database...');
    $query = "SELECT `s_id`, `s_asset`, `s_status`, `s_lots`, `s_price`, `s_date`, `s_market`, `s_type` FROM `parties` WHERE `s_date` BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY `s_id` DESC";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Data connection lost.');
    
    $msList = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
        $id = $row['s_id'];
        $signal = strtoupper($row['s_asset']);
        $status = $row['s_status'];
        $lots = $row['s_lots'] . ' Lot MAX';
        $price = $row['s_price'];
        $market = $row['s_market']; 
        $type = $row['s_type'];
    
        $msList[$id] = Array($signal, $price, $date, $time, $lots, $status, $type, $market);
    }
    
//ループでechoしている内容    (このデータの行数を変えられるようにしたい）
    foreach ($msList as $id => $ms) {　　　
        echo '<div class="list-data">
                  <h2>'.$ms[0].'</h3>'.$ms[6].'
                  <h3>'.$ms[1].'</h3> 
                  <div>
                      <p>'.$ms[2].'&nbsp;'.$ms[3].'</p>
                  </div>
              </div>';
    }
    ?>
```

**わからない点について追記**
現状作ったコードは下記です。下記のような感じ？のコードの流れになるのかなと思っております。

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function change_num(){
                var selectNum = document.getElementById('list-num');  //プルダウンのselectを取得
                var listData = document.getElementsByClassName('list-data');　//1データ
                var n = selectNum.getAttribute("value");  //選択された行数を取得

                for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                    n番目までのデータをechoする
                }
            }

そして、上記のforeach内でこのfunctionを呼び出すようにする。
```

難しく考えすぎているのでしょうか、**どうやって選択された行数を取得すればよいのか**、また**次のページが必要な場合それをどのようにコードに反映させればよいのか**がわからない状況です。

サンプルとなるようなコードを教えていただければ大変助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考サイトみましたが、どこにつまづいているのか分からなかったので、質問者さんが参考サイトと同じような実装をするのに、今分からなくなっている点を明記してもらった方が、的を射た回答がつきやすくなると思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記しました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 正確にやりたいことはなんでしょうか？ 「可変なリストの表示」自体はご自身が提示なさっているリンク先にやり方が載っているので、ほぼそのまま真似すれば完成するはずですが、質問者さんはMySQLからデータを取り出そうとしていますね。このことから、本当にやりたいことは、「MySQLから取り出したデータを可変なリストに表示したい」だと推測します。もし、リンク先を見ても、まだJavaScriptによる可変なリストを使う方法がわからないというのであれば、まずはMySQLからデータを取得するのは一旦辞めて、JavaScriptによる可変なリストの作り方を習得するのに専念したほうがよいと考えます。2つのことを同時にするとどちらが問題を起こしているのか切り分けが難しくなりますし、回答者もどちらで悩んでおられるのかわからず、回答を書きづらいと思います。

Comment: 追記：もし「MySQLから選択された数だけデータを取り出してリスト表示したい」のであれば、リンク先の書き方は、全てのデータ（もしくはまとまったデータを）あらかじめ持ってくる必要があるので、エレガントな方法とは言えない場合があります。この場合はPHPで押し切るか、Ajax等を使ったほうがエレガントかもしれません。（念の為追記しておきます）

Comment: shingo.nakanishiさんもご指摘されているように、やりたいことの詳細（例えばこれは学習中の課題の一つなのか、実務でシステム開発中の問題なのかなども含めて）は何になるでしょうか。データ数が膨大だと正面から実装しても使い物にならないものになりかねませんので、別のアプローチが必要になる場合もあります。

Comment: > shingo.nakanishiさん　コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、やりたいことは「MySQLから取り出したデータを可変なリストに表示したい」でした。伝わりづらい文章で申し訳ございません。「MySQLから取り出したデータをリストにして表示する」まではできたので、「可変なリスト表示の方法」がわからなかった部分です。業務で必要だったため質問させていただいておりました。結局業務で必要なくなってしまったのですが、ご指摘いただいた通り、JavaScriptによる可変なリストの作り方に自信がないため、まずはこれを練習して習得に励みたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: >Sugiyama Koichi さん　コメントありがとうございます。業務で必要だったため質問させていただいておりましたが、結局業務で必要なくなってしまいました。参考にぜひお聞きしたいのですが、「データ数が膨大な場合の別のアプローチ」というのは、どういったものなのでしょうか。（毎回すべてのデータを引き出すのではなく、選択されたフィルター分のデータのみを引き出す、等でしょうか？）業務につき始めたばかりで初心者の質問で恐縮ですが、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: そのあたりは「ページング」と呼ばれる概念になります。まずはこちらの単語で検索してみてください。

Comment: >keitaro_so さん　わかりました。ありがとうございました^^